# PowerShell 5.1 - How to uninstall module which is currently use

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, powershell-5.0, powershell-module

We are using some PowerShell modules in one deployment PowerShell script. Using following command we are installing module (i.e. XXXX) into "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules".

```
Install-Module -Name "XXXX" -AllowClobber -RequiredVersion "XXXX" -Repository "XXXX" -Scope AllUsers
```

Now once we used the functionality of this module, we uninstall it at the end of deployment script using following command.

```
Remove-Module -Name "XXXX" -force
Uninstall-Module -Name "XXXX"  -AllVersions -force
```

But this uninstall module command gives following error.

```
WARNING: The version '###' of module 'XXXX' is currently in use. Retry the operation after closing the
applications.
PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package : Module 'XXXX' is in currently in use.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2046 char:21
+ ...        $null = PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage) [Uninstall-Packag
   e], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ModuleIsInUse,Uninstall-Package,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.Uninstall
   Package
```

Does anybody have any idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem could be that your existing PowerShell session is "locking" the module by loading possible elements from it (such as global variables or constants) even though you are trying to unload it (`Remove-Module`).

The cleanest way to be sure it isn't locked is to exit the PowerShell session.  If you need to keep the session around to do "stuff" afterwards, trying starting a new PowerShell session (nested session) just before you make use of the module, then exit it at the end.

Comment: Royal pain in my backside but that appears to be the reason and solution.

Comment: If PowerShell is using the package and you need to exit PowerShell to remove it, how do you then run `Remove-Module` without restarting PowerShell and re-locking the package?

Comment: Using a different console, like windows cmd-prompt(for eg.) generally works when powershell is locking some module.

Comment: In my case, an editor extension (PowerShell for VSCode) was the culprit preserving a module reference. Don't forget about those.

Comment: I had an AWS module installed in three different places for three different needs (user,admin,vscode) and had to uninstall them all.

Answer (score 28):

As mentioned in the [original answer by E Bekker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46324691/7419319), modules may get stuck in session.
Closing the PowerShell session, and running uninstall in a new one should help.

### Handling auto-loading

As [Keith mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626470/powershell-5-1-how-to-uninstall-module-which-is-currently-use/46324691#comment102452596_46324691), a module may get locked if it's auto-loaded. If it happens via profile, adding `-NoProfile` to the uninstall script should help:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Uninstall-Module X"
```

Some modules, like PSReadLine, get loaded even in such session, and may require extra `-NonInteractive` argument:

```
powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "Uninstall-Module X"
```

I have yet to find such case, but if it still doesn't help, one may use `(Get-InstalledModule -Name X).InstalledLocation` to find where the module got installed, and remove it by other means (last resort). If another / older version of the module was bundled with PowerShell, it's best to avoid manual removal not to break it.

### Workarounds

- Maybe in this case uninstall is not necessary, and it's possible to install your module, keep it, and update it with `Update-InstalledModule` when needed?
- Many modules can get imported without installation. `Import-Module` with the path of .psd1 file is likely to work. Still, it doesn't make `Remove-Module` work 100%.
- If security is a concern, one can install the module only for the service user with `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser`, and/or restrict PowerShell usage with `Set-ExecutionPolicy`, which can be run with `-Scope` argument too.

Answer (score 18):

In my case, I solved this this way:

1. Close PowerShell.
2. Really, close PowerShell. Open up Task Manager and find any background instances of PowerShell, as in either or both powershell.exe / pwsh.exe.
3. Delete the unwanted module folders from C:\Users\${USER}\Documents\PowerShell\Modules

Comment: Really close PowerShell is most important thing here

Comment: I had to delete mine from `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\<module>\<version>`.  I think the path can be figured from `(Get-Module -ListAvailable <ThePackageName>).Path`

Comment: For those with mandatory cloud sync enabled to one drive the path is;

    %OneDrive%/Documents/WindowsPowerShell/Modules

Answer (score 7):

As of late 2021, I faced the same issue with pwsh7.2 and the PSFzf module.
What worked for me:

1. Close/Force Close all instances of PowerShell/pwsh through task manager.
2. Start a new instance of pwsh without profile. Win+R > `pwsh -NoProfile`
3. Run `Uninstall-Module -Name PSfzf -Force`