# What are the powershell module version dependencies for Terraform azure provider?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

Currently using terraform = 0.11.14 and azurerm provider = 1.29.0.  Where can I find the required powershell modules / versions for my current azurerm provider version?

For example is Az.Accounts 1.6.0 ok for my current azurerm provider or do I need an older version?

Windows 10
Powershell 5.1

Comment: Not clearly what do you want to do? Can you provide more details? the terraform code?

Comment: Getting this warning while running terraform script:   "(local-exec): WARNING: The version '1.6.0' of module 'Az.Accounts' is currently in use. Retry the operation after closing the applications."  Caused me to wonder what the terraform pre-reqs are for individual powershell modules.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware that there is the required PowerShell modules/versions for the current Azure provider version. It's recommended to use the latest [Azure PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.4.0) version. If you're interested in the Azure provider's latest features, you could check out the [changelog](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for version information and release notes.

For the error in your comment, it indicated that your existing PowerShell session is "locking" the module by loading possible elements from it. Since `local-exec` provider invokes a process on the machine running Terraform, not on the resource. When you run it in terraform, it actually runs on local PowerShell. I don't think it will be related to the terraform version. This error might be due to your existing PowerShell session. You could exit it or open a new PowerShell session. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626470/powershell-5-1-how-to-uninstall-module-which-is-currently-use).

Hope it helps.